# No error from Typescript compiler when constructor receives different parameters types as the ones from the implemented interface

Tags: typescript

I have tried the following code:

```
interface IRectangle {
    height: number;
    width: number;
    getArea: ()=>number;
}

module Shapes {
    export class Rectangle implements IRectangle {
        constructor(public height, public width) {
        }

        getArea() {
            return this.width * this.height;
        }
    }
}

console.log(new Shapes.Rectangle(12, 'a').getArea());
```

I'm expecting that the typescript compiler should give me an error when trying to supply a character to the constructor (last code line) even tough the interface (IRectangle) says that both fields should be of type number. But I don't receive any error. Why is the reason behind this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the typescript compiler to see this error you could declare your constructor like constructor(public height:number, public width:number)

To understand, why it doesn't do it in your example there is a good explanation [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#classes-static-properties)

and [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#interfaces-class-types) There is an important distinction between the static side and the instance side of a class. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting the difference between static and instance side, it makes sense now.